# Java Android: Change locale onClick in mainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, localization, locale

I want my app support 2 language, en and it, so I create a Switch to change the locale in the mainActivity.
The idea is to change Locale and restart the activity passing the new language.
I use API 28 to support more devices.

I tried this but it doesn't work.
Sometimes change the locale but only once.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        language = findViewById(R.id.language);


        String lan = getIntent().getStringExtra("lan");
        if(lan != null) {
            if(lan.equals("ita")) {
                language.setChecked(true);
                lang = "ita";
            }else lang = "eng";
        }else if(Locale.getDefault().toString().startsWith("it")){
            language.setChecked(true);
            lang = "ita";
        }

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(view -> enterRoom());
        language.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
            lang = b? "ita" : "eng";
            setLocale(lang);
        });
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang){
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang.substring(0, 2));
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        i.putExtra("lan",lang);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying, I finally fixed this using updateConfiguration even though it's deprecated

```
private void setLocale(String lang){
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale(lang.substring(0, 2)));
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.putExtra("lan",locale);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch languageSwitch;
    private String lang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the language preference from the intent or default to the device locale
        String lan = getIntent().getStringExtra("lan");
        if (lan == null) {
            lan = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        }

        // Set the activity language based on the preference
        lang = lan.equals("it") ? "it" : "en";
        setLocale(lang);

        // Set the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find views and set up click listeners
        languageSwitch = findViewById(R.id.language_switch);
        languageSwitch.setChecked(lang.equals("it"));
        languageSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
            lang = isChecked ? "it" : "en";
            setLocale(lang);
        });

        Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(v -> enterRoom());
    }

    private void setLocale(String lang) {
        // Update the app's language configuration
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        // Restart the activity with the new configuration
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lan", lang);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void enterRoom() {
        // Start the room activity with the current language preference
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RoomActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lan", lang);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Try this sample code separatly and change it with your code.

Comment: I don't think it will solve the problem, rather you go into an infinite loop by calling setLocale at the beginning, it create a new Activity and repeat.